# Adjusting width using inline CSS

Tags: css, width, inline

I am new to CSS/HTML and I am having some trouble adjusting the width of my page. I'm sure the solution is very simple and obvious lol.

On this page: http://www.bodylogicmd.com/appetites-and-aphrodisiacs - I am trying to set the width to 100% so that the content spans the entire width of the page. The problem I am running into is that when I try to add inline CSS, the external stylesheet called in the head is superseding the inline. I am using Joomla, so the editor let's edit the body, not the head (unless I create a custom module that rewrites code for the head).

I do not want to re-write/edit the external (main) stylesheet, since I am using this page for a contest and it is only running for about 1 month.

Anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this using inline CSSS and what the code would be?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Inline CSS will *always* take precedence over styles defined elsewhere, unless you've got an `!important` somewhere in your other CSS. So, you should either remove that, or perhaps simply declare `!important` in your inline styles. But that should not, ordinarily, be required.

Comment: Can you say what element you're trying to alter the width of? If it's contained within another element, and that element has a fixed width, then your element will only ever reach 100% of its parent's width. I hope that's clear.

Comment: To which elements are you trying to add the inline style(s)?  I see that there are explicit widths at various places (#main, #content, #column2, .box2).  You need to be sure you override all the appropriate external styles to get the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
#main, #content, .landing-wrapper, #column2 .box2 {width: auto;}
#column2 {width: auto; float: none;}
```

You should be able to place this in the head of your template's index.php, though I would personally add it to the bottom of the theme's main stylesheet. How long it's there isn't a factor.

Comment: isherwood is close to your answer, you will just have to 'inline' override the template .css of inject a new .css file in your header, AFTER others from template.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the #main selector and set it wider there.  The body is always going to be 100% wide unless you explicitly set it otherwise.  In your case the #main container is the wrapper around the whole page, this is what you want to set.  I'd also recommend looking up the "box model" and understanding how that works before going too much further.  It will save you much weeping and gnashing of teeth.  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

try adding inline .css {width: 100%; (or auto)} to :
- #main
- #content
- .landing-wrapper
- #column2 .box2